# java best practices

Tags: java, optimization

Need to find out more optimized ways to code in Java.

Here is a very simple sample code

```
int index1 = line.indexOf(" ", word1.length() + 1);
if (!line.isEmpty() && index1 != -1) {
line = line.substring(word1.length(), index1).trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

or

```
if(!line.isEmpty() && line.indexOf(" ",word1.length()+1) != -1){
line = line.substring(word1.length(), index1).trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

What I noticed is the most of the times you have to decide between better code readability or perhaps more optimized code. Which one is better approach?

Comment: For the folks who don't have a Java environment before them, or don't feel like a compiler; I'd suggest also writing an example of an input line and the expected result.

Comment: @Ali - when are you going to accept those answers like you said you would??

Comment: Stephen I am doing that. Seriously, I am not familiar with this forum and I am trying to cope up with all the rules.

Comment: somehow i just wanna say a little bit clue:
Please share this article: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/5580/BP_Writing_efficient_code_446999_11.jsp

Comment: http://www.javabench.in/2016/11/while-developing-programming-in-java.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In all cases where performance increases are marginal or not completely justified, aim for

> **Readability**

Comment: +1: make it readable, but not too hard to optimize, if you see there is room for improvement in the future.

Comment: but in the example would the second approach be better of would it be better to declare a new variable like index1 supposing that the code is inside a big loop and the variable is going to be initiated every time. Thanks

Comment: @Ali, readability is in many ways **subjective**. **I** think the first approach is more readable, although you can probably improve it further, as solovyev pointed out, by using e.g., a tokenizer.

Comment: -1 - talks vaguely about "performance" and "readability". Not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution in THAT particular case is to use StringTokenizer and you will not have such a problem (i mean readability)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve - is word1 the first word of line ?

If so, I would consider something along the following lines more readable:

```
String parts[] = line.split(" +");
if (parts.length > 1) {
    line = parts[1];
}
```